# Joining Lists Within A List?

Tags: python, list, join

I am trying to make a join of some lists within a list in python here is an example of what I am doing (the lists are much bigger in the real code):

```
import itertools

listenv = ["IN","VC","VS"]
listsize = ["U17-1","U17-2"]

listevnsize = list(itertools.product(listenv, listsize,))

print listevnsize
#This results in [('IN', 'U17-1'), ('IN', 'U17-2'), ('VC', 'U17-1'), ('VC', 'U17-2'), ('VS', 'U17-1'), ('VS', 'U17-2')]
```

What I want to do now is to combine the inner lists with a - for instance I would like the result to be:

```
[('IN-U17-1'), ('IN-U17-2'), ('VC-U17-1'), ('VC-U17-2'), ('VS-U17-1'), ('VS-U17-2')]
```

So in other words I would like to join the inner lists, but when I tried using:

```
listevnsizejoined = '-'.join(map(str,listevnsizezip))
```

As suggested in another question, this is joining all of the outer lists into one big string like this:

```
(('IN', 'U17-1'),)-(('IN', 'U17-2'),)-(('VC', 'U17-1'),)-(('VC', 'U17-2'),)-(('VS', 'U17-1'),)
```

FINAL SOLUTION:

```
import itertools

listenv = ["IN","VC","VS","VX","RH","HT","DP","AD","PT","PTRH","WP","WPRH","CYVX","HM"];
listsize = ["U17-1","U17-2"];
listseventeenGR = ["17P:3","17P:4","17P:5.5","17P:7","17P:10","17P:16","17P:22","17P:28","17P:40","17P:49","17P:55","17P:70","17P:100"]


listevnsize = list(itertools.product(listenv, listsize,))

listenvsizejoined = []

for x in listevnsize:
    listenvsizejoined.append('-'.join(i for i in x))

print listenvsizejoined
```

This is the final solution for combining two lists in all combinations, and then joining those inner lists with a dash.

Comment: Edited in order to add the output of the advice from other postings. I wanted to fully show my code and why my join command is not working as I intended, maybe I have used it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `str.join`

```
S.join(iterable) -> string

Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
iterable.  The separator between elements is S.

l = []

for x in listevnsize:
    l.append('-'.join(i for i in x))
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, and has a great explanation. Thank you, for anyone that wants the full answer I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This would work, just use zip

```
new_list = []
for i,j in zip(listenv, listsize):
    new_list.append(('{0}-{1}').format(i,j))
```

Comment: I have tried using this, but I need the original command of the combination:

listevnsize = list(itertools.product(listenv, listsize,))

This is necessary in order to get all combinations of the first two. What arguments should I put in for list1 and list2?

Answer (score 0):

```
listenvsize = ["{}-{}".format(x,y) for x in listenv for y in listsize]
```

The result will not be a list of tuples anyway since there is only one element in the tuple you want.